# Two loops in a list with NA's - R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, row

Suppose I have a dataframe (df) where each row ends up with NA's.

```
    > df
    #      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
    # [1,]    1    7    9    4   NA
    # [2,]    3    6   NA   NA   NA
    # [3,]    1    6    6    4    3
    # [4,]    7    7   NA   NA   NA
    # [5,]    4    3    1    8   NA
```

I created a list with each row without the NA'S

```
nn <-c()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  nn[[i]]<-t(na.omit(t(df[i,])))
}
```

For example, nn[[1]]={1,7,9,4}.

Now I want to determinate the distance between each pair of rows but only considering the minimum number of observations of the pair. For example, first row has 4 observations and third row has 5 observations. So the distance between first and thrid row will only take in account the first 4 observations. I did this code which works! But it's not automatic:

```
i <- 1
dd <- c()
for (j in 1:nrow(df)){
  dd[j] <- dist(as.data.frame(rbind(nn[[i]][1:min(lengths(nn[i]),lengths(nn[j]))],nn[[j]][1:min(lengths(nn[i]),lengths(nn[j]))])))
}
dd1 <- dd
```

With `i<-1` i calculated the distance between row 1 and the rest of the rows. And R saves dd1 with those distances.
If I do `i<-2` and do `dd2 <- dd` I get the same for the second row, and so forth..

The real dataset I'm working is much bigger and I want to do this automatically. I tried to put i vary between 1 and nrow(df) and do something like dd[i,j] but doesn't work.
Can someone help me do this automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You should not remove the NA values, they will help when calculating the distances.

So starting with your original data:

```
df
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  1  7  9  4 NA
2  3  6 NA NA NA
3  1  6  6  4  3
4  7  7 NA NA NA
5  4  3  1  8 NA
```

We attempt to calculate the distances between all the rows using `dist()` in one go:

```
dst <- as.matrix(dist(df, diag=TRUE, upper=TRUE))
dst
          1        2        3        4         5
1  0.000000 3.535534 3.535534 9.486833 11.456439
2  3.535534 0.000000 3.162278 6.519202  5.000000
3  3.535534 3.162278 0.000000 9.617692  8.587782
4  9.486833 6.519202 9.617692 0.000000  7.905694
5 11.456439 5.000000 8.587782 7.905694  0.000000
```

Now these values are a bit weird, not sure if this is what you are looking for. Reading `help(dist)` we see this bit:

> If some columns
>        are excluded in calculating a Euclidean, Manhattan, Canberra or
>        Minkowski distance, the sum is scaled up proportionally to the
>        number of columns used.  If all pairs are excluded when
>        calculating a particular distance, the value is ‘NA’.

What this says is - if your data has NA, the distances are scaled, so that the missing values also add to the distance. This makes the distances comparable in size, despite some elements having NA values.

Now if you do not want this, we have to re-adjust these distances so that they are not scaled. But first we need to understand how they are scaled.

The function sees that for some specific distance 2 out of 5 columns were used and the others were NA. What it does is it multiplies the sum within the distance by 5/2 and then takes the square-root value (as per Euclidean formula).

So what we need to do is 1st - obtain those ratios, 2nd - take square root values of those ratios, and 3rd - readjust.

We start by, for each distance, getting the number of NA elements used to calculate them:

```
nas <- outer(rowSums(is.na(df)), rowSums(is.na(df)), FUN=pmax)
nas
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    1    3    1
[2,]    3    3    3    3    3
[3,]    1    3    0    3    1
[4,]    3    3    3    3    3
[5,]    1    3    1    3    1
```

Now using this, we get the fraction of data that had NA values for each distance:

```
frac <- (ncol(df)-nas) / ncol(df)
frac
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.8  0.4  0.8  0.4  0.8
[2,]  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4
[3,]  0.8  0.4  1.0  0.4  0.8
[4,]  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4
[5,]  0.8  0.4  0.8  0.4  0.8
```

We see, for example, that for pair 1-2 we had 3 missing values and 2 available values. So the available ones comprised 40% of the whole.

Next we take squared roots of those ratios and multiply them with the distances we got (those adjusted distances) in order to restore this scaling:

```
res <- dst * sqrt(frac)
res
          1        2        3        4         5
1  0.000000 2.236068 3.162278 6.000000 10.246951
2  2.236068 0.000000 2.000000 4.123106  3.162278
3  3.162278 2.000000 0.000000 6.082763  7.681146
4  6.000000 4.123106 6.082763 0.000000  5.000000
5 10.246951 3.162278 7.681146 5.000000  0.000000
```

And this is your result. So to sum it all up:

```
dst  <- as.matrix(dist(df, diag=TRUE, upper=TRUE))
nas  <- outer(rowSums(is.na(df)), rowSums(is.na(df)), FUN=pmax)
frac <- (ncol(df)-nas) / ncol(df)
res  <- dst * sqrt(frac)
```

Comment: I understand your idea for the distance and it's great. but my question here is more about how to implement dd1, dd2, dd3, etc.. automaticlly instead of doing it manually